# ASP.NET MVC 4 Timer/Timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, timer, timeout

I am creating online Test application. It has instruction pages at start of test and end of test.
Now when user start the test it is first visits the “Test Instruction Page” and click on Next will start the Test.
So requirement is when user visits the “Test instruction page” and not clicked on Next button so after 2 minutes it should automatically redirected to Questions page( basically call the DynamicContent action). I have View which has the “Test Instruction” and Next button in the Controller I have action it can either show the “Test Instruction” or the Question.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DynamicContent(DynamicContentViewModel dynamicContentViewModel)
{
    If(Instruction not displayed)
    {
       // Display instruction
    }
    else
    {
      // call the Question action which displays question 
    }
}
```

I have tried below but its not working.

```
<location path="Controller/DynamicContent">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime  executionTimeout="5"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

How to achieve this functionality? Also I have to display elapsed time on page.
Thanks.